# reboot and permissions in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: reboot

in Ubuntu 16.04

```
UNIX_lab@MyComputer:~$ `sudo reboot -f`
Rebooting.
Failed to reboot: Invalid argument
```

I don't know this solution.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
UNIX_lab@MyComputer:~$ sudo reboot -f
```

Should work, i.e. w/o `` (this indicates command substitution and is only needed in scripts)

Use command substitution e.g. like this (in a script)

```
mkdir /home/`whoami`
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm sorry, I really wrote {UNIX_lab@MyComputer:~$ sudo reboot -f} But it couldn't work.

Comment: ok... what about `sudo halt` or ` sudo shutdown`  etc?

Comment: NO, It can`t work. The message is ...
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
Failed to talk to init daemon.